# Joining 2 csv files in python based on index values

Tags: python

In python, I want to join / merge 2 csv files based on index values.Both the files have index column and based on the index we have to add a particular column from one csv to another csv.

Ex: csv 1:

```
Index   topic   subject
1115    fcfs       Operating System
1923    dml        Database Management System
835     jdbc       Object_oriented_programing
1866    joints     Database Management System
```

CSV 2:

```
Index  Questions
180    When an object is seen from front..
1115   Case in which fcfs is the best algo
959    How does the scheduler know the time..
```

Output csv:

```
Index topic Subject           Questions
1115   fcfs Operating System  Case in which..
```

Pleas help me to write a code in Python

Comment: CSV 1 has 20 rows and CSV 2 has 500 rows .. I want to map all 500 rows in CSV 2 with CSV 1 values..Is it possible

Answer (score 3):

This is an ideal use-case for [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd


csv_1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
csv_2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')

merged = csv_1.merge(csv_2, on='Index')
merged.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

You can read more about [opening your files here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [merging here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But CSV 1 has 20 rows CSV2 has 500 rows. Can I map all 500 to CSV 1 which has only 20 rows.

Comment: It would depend on what's in the CSV files. If there is no matching index in CSV1 then these rows will not match in the example. You could use the option `how='outer'` on the `merge` operation, but this would likely result in half filled rows.